# Get a specific tag

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying here to get the previous "img" tag when clicking on the 3rd "i" tag :

```
<div>
    <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="image2"/>
    <div id="image_options">
        <i class="material-icons md-36">account_box</i>
        <label>djbaptou</label>
        <div id="left_icons">
            <i class="material-icons md-36 fav">favorite_border</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-36 purple">question_answer</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-36 full_screen">settings_overscan</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code :

```
$(".full_screen").click(function(){
    var img = $(this).parent().parent().closest("img");
    modal.css("display", "block");
    modalImg.attr("src", img.attr("src"));
});
```

But when i do a "alert(img);" it says that this is undefined

Any ideas ?

Comment: just use `closest("img")`. No need for parent().parent()

Comment: `closest` means *closest* ancestor. Your `img` is not ancestor of any other element.

Comment: First of all, combining parent and closest is kind of redundant. Secondly, try this: `$(this).parents('#image_options').prev('img')` ***OR*** `$(this).closest('#image_options').prev('img')` The `closest` is like parents, except that it only gets first one it comes across. although, in this case, using .parents on a `id` will also only get one.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: No point to `$(this).parents('#image_options')...` unless the structure is variable and you only want to find it if it happens to be a parent (which is rare). Simply `$("#image_options")...` is all one needs.

Comment: AFAIK `closest` works on ancestors only, your `img` is not an ancestor of any element, so it wouldn't be matched by any `closest`.

Comment: Thank you guys ! it works now

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `true`, i was just pointing out different ways of looking up. then again, what if he has dynamically loaded sections and each section has said ID for purpose of this style of reference. bad coding I know, but it happens.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: *"...but it happens"* It do indeed. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I take it you've done contract clean ups too? :P any who, good answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`closest` won't work, because the `i` element isn't a *descendant* of the `img` element (by definition; `img` elements can't have child elements).

You could use `parent().parent().prev()` in that specific case, but it's fragile; the slightest change to the markup as you revise things over time will mess it up. What I'd do is add a class to the overall `div` and then use `closest(".the-class").find("img")`.

Or of course, since the div with the `i` elements has an `id`, just `$("#image_options").prev()`.

Here's an example of the class option where clicking that third `i` element changes the image from your user icon to mine:

```js
$("i.purple").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".the-class").find("img").attr("src", "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG");
});
```

```html
<div class="the-class">
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/10153295750512607/picture?type=small" alt="image2"/>
    <div id="image_options">
        <i class="material-icons md-36">account_box</i>
        <label>djbaptou</label>
        <div id="left_icons">
            <i class="material-icons md-36 fav">favorite_border</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-36 purple">question_answer</i>
            <i class="material-icons md-36 full_screen">settings_overscan</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```